# How could I convert messy Stanford Core NLP string object into JSON

Tags: ruby, json, casting, stanford-nlp

The Ruby Stanford Core NLP gem returns messy objects.

Example 1:

```
 => "[produced nsubjpass:[lbs amod:[many advmod:how] prep:[of pobj:CO2]] auxpass:is prep:[from pcomp:[burning dobj:[gallons num:12 prep:[of pobj:gas]]]]]"
```

Example 2:

```
 -> produced-VBN (root)
   -> lbs-NNS (nsubjpass)
     -> many-JJ (amod)
       -> how-WRB (advmod)
     -> of-IN (prep)
       -> CO2-NN (pobj)
   -> is-VBZ (auxpass)
   -> from-IN (prep)
     -> burning-VBG (pcomp)
       -> gallons-NNS (dobj)
         -> 12-CD (num)
         -> of-IN (prep)
           -> gas-NN (pobj)
```

Example 3:

```
  @sentence.to_s
=> "-> produced-VBN (root)\n  -> lbs-NNS (nsubjpass)\n    -> many-JJ (amod)\n      -> how-WRB (advmod)\n    -> of-IN (prep)\n      -> CO2-NN (pobj)\n  -> is-VBZ (auxpass)\n  -> from-IN (prep)\n    -> burning-VBG (pcomp)\n      -> gallons-NNS (dobj)\n        -> 12-CD (num)\n        -> of-IN (prep)\n          -> gas-NN (pobj)\n"
```

How could I convert any of those objects into something like JSON using Ruby?

Comment: What have you tried? Are there methods for iterating over these "messy objects"? I imagine it would be a simple matter of converting to a `Hash` then using a JSON gem to convert.

Comment: everything. i'm out of ideas. The data structure is a mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [following excerpt](https://github.com/louismullie/treat/blob/master/lib/treat/workers/processors/parsers/stanford.rb#L55) for how to iterate the results and build the corresponding tree. I'll leave it as an exercise to convert the resulting tree into JSON format.

Note you could also skip ahead and use [Treat](https://github.com/louismullie/treat/) directly to retrieve the parsed tree of the sentence.